# Drupal 8 Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' DrupalBootstrapStyles.php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have this error (**Warning: Illegal string offset 'name' in Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\Provider\DrupalBootstrapStyles->Drupal\bootstrap\Plugin\Provider{closure}() (line 71 of themes\bootstrap\src\Plugin\Provider\DrupalBootstrapStyles.php).)** when I open a web page of my site. If anyone have an idea how to solve that. I use a child theme from ( bootstrap 3 for drupal)
Link Image of the error:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1An9ZDdhDKibK5UnOfvOl821sKd0MdPFP/view

Comment: Generally, this error means you're doing something like `$test = 'some string';` then something like `$name = $test['name']`  essentially, whatever variable you're working with is expected to be an array and it is not. Check the data you're feeding to that class

Comment: @WesleySmith Yeah, but Im using Drupal 8, I'm not touching any of source code. I dont know what I should do exactly. looking for the bootstrap theme ? or updating core ? or what exactly

Comment: Id start by looking at line 71 of themes\bootstrap\src\Plugin\Provider\DrupalBootstrapStyles.php, figuring out what exactly its trying to get a "name" index from and follow it back from there. Id guess that its some kind of missing configuration or something not being set correctly when setting up the view or model or whatever powers the page/app.

Comment: https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/src%21Plugin%21Provider%21DrupalBootstrapStyles.php/8.x-3.x shows that line 71  is looping over `$data['files']` and trying to get `$file['name']`, perhaps somewhere in your configuration theres an array of string file names that should be an array of arrays? follow that back to where $data['files'] comes from

Comment: @WesleySmith Im using a field type Image (Unlimited). I will check that

Comment: see my patch https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-02-13/bootstrap-provide_missing_css-3113579-02.patch

Comment: My patch probably not needed, there is another workaround, please see the upstream issue, there's a setting in bootstrap to disable the cdn and there's another stop to do, see the details in this thread: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3113579#comment-13468303

Answer (score 1):

also seeing this in one of our environments, there is a workaround (disable the cdn setting and another step)

see the explanation and issue thread below 
https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3113579

Comment: Thank you @Joseph I will use it

Comment: My patch probably not needed, there is another workaround, please see the upstream issue, there's a setting in bootstrap to disable the cdn https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3113579#comment-13468303

Comment: we ended up using my own patch anyhow for a high-profile site that is almost ready to be put into production, it was too complex to figure out another workaround or we just moved onto other challenges and accepted this solution.

Comment: still using the patch I created, here is the rerolled patch for the latest bootstrap 8.x-3.23 vesion: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3113579#comment-13873704

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting this, but its happening in IIS only.  On my XAMPP server its fine.  Anyone else using IIS?

Also, there should be a fallback option if I am running this on development servers that can't access the internet.  Seems like there is an external call to the Cdn from the php code to load the Bootstrap styles...

Comment: ok, I have created a patch, it adds the missing css globally and does an if isset for undefined index on the provider plugin.  https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3113579#comment-13464878

Comment: My patch probably not needed, there is another workaround, please see the upstream issue, there's a setting in bootstrap to disable the cdn https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3113579#comment-13468303

Comment: NOTE: I just rerolled the patch fix for this, patch 16 here: https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/3113579#comment-13873704